# blank page after export pdf in Ms Word

Tags: windows, pdf, export, cpu-word

why do I find blank pdf pages, even though in the word file I don't find blank pages or insert blank pages. Thank you
[Source file or Word file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiX9b.png)
[Result file or Pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFxlm.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your document check if number style is checked as

> "odd and even pages different"

if yes, then word automatically creates more or odd or even blank page. So uncheck it, to get rid off blank pages